# How to differentiate files of same name?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-7

I am using netbeans, and working on a web application. This application has multiple pages. Each of these pages has code which is recorded in the project as `/project/web/pages/pagename/index.html/`. I would like to edit two of these files at once in netbeans. That I can do no issue. However, both tab names merely read "index.html".

Is there a way to set it to differentiate them somehow? Preferably if the tab names would list the parent folder as well, ala sublime text.

so that the tab titles would read `page1/index.html` and `page2/index.html`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to go tools > options > appearance > check the "show parent folder names in tab title" checkbox.

However, this is a temporary solution and is not 'intelligent'.

Comment: [1] Your answer seems to completely address the issue you raised in the question, so why not also accept it? [2] That setting persists across sessions. Why are you calling it a _"temporary solution"_? [3] What does _"intelligent"_ mean in this context? [4] What would you like NetBeans to be doing other than providing the option you have specified?

Comment: I would like an 'intelligent' feature like sublime text 3, where parent directories are listed only when two files of the same name are open. As it stands, I will have to manually turn off this setting when I am done working with these same-named files. I would like netbeans to do this for me.

Comment: OK, understood. I'm pretty sure that can't be done in NetBeans, but you could [create a NetBeans Bug Report to raise it as a request for a new feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-2967?filter=allissues&orderby=created+DESC).